# C2451: conditional expression of type 'QString' is illegal

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

I'm having a problem when using QDirIterator. I need to read the subdirectories from a folder, so i pass a QString to QDirIterator as parameter. But when i call "while" it gives me this error: **C2451: conditional expression of type 'QString' is illegal**

```
QDirIterator iter4(directory, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

while(iter4.next()){
}
```

Anyone got any explanation? I'm using Qt Creator 4.2.0 based on Qt 5.7.1.

Thanks for the attention and help.

Comment: seems like there is no conversion available from `QString` to `bool`, btw what do you actually mean with `while(iter4.next())` ? It should run while there are more subdirs?

Comment: Strange, because i already used something like this in another program i made and it worked...

Comment: can it be that in the other program it was a pointer to a `QString` ? Pointers can always be used as a condition

Comment: Maybe try something like `while(!iter4.isNull()){ item.next(); }`

Comment: @George should be `while(iter4.hasNext())`

Comment: Yes, it should read all subdirs and then return when finished.

Comment: Oh! Of course! i did not saw that! Thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means just what it says. Apparently there is no conversion available from `QString` to `bool`. The correct usage would be

```
while(iter4.hasNext()){
    //...
}
```

See also [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html#next). Sometimes it really helps to rtfm ;)